# Escaping quantifier braces after hash in regex

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the correct way to escape a hash character followed by quantification with braces in a regex? I want to detect a sequence of hash characters repeated within a given number of times. I want something like:

```
/#{1, 6}/
```

without interpolation. I cannot turn off interpolation entirely for the regex because I use it in other portions of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use back-slash `\` as the escape character e.g.

```
    /\#{1, 6}/
```